# schedule cron job on aws beanstalk rails container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron, whenever, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the whenever gem to configure my crontab and schedule cron jobs. my config/schedule.rb file has the following content:

```
set :environment, "test"
set :output, {:error => "/var/log/cron_error.log", :standard => "/var/log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.minutes do
   runner 'TickerSymbol.update_prices'
end
```

At the moment I am invoking Rails.logger.debug ... in the TickerSymbol.update_prices method. Also, notice in the schedule.rb file that I am trying to write the output from the scheduled cron job to /var/logs/*.log. This is not working. When I view the logs on S3 or via the Beanstalk management console I see other log files from the /var/log directory, but I do not see my cron log files.

My .ebextensions/[app name].config file has the following content:

```
sources: 
  /aws-scripts-mon: http://ec2-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudwatch-samples/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts.zip

option_settings:
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value: XXX
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: XXX
  - option_name: BUNDLE_WITHOUT
    value: "production:development"
  - option_name: RACK_ENV
    value: test
  - option_name: RAILS_ENV
    value: test
  - option_name: RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS
    value: true

container_commands:
  01-setupcron:
    command: echo "*/5 * * * * root perl /aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail --aws-access-key-id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --aws-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_KEY > /dev/null" > /etc/cron.d/cwpump
  02-changeperm:
    command: chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cwpump
  03-changeperm:
    command: chmod u+x /aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl
  04-rake_routes:
    command: rake routes
  05-whenever:
    command: whenever -c
    command: whenever -i [app name] --update-crontab
    command: whenever -f
    command: crontab -l
    leader_only: true
```

Following is the content from my log file which is generated during my deployment with git aws.push. This log entry confirms that whenever is generating the crontab file as expected.

```
2013-04-06 14:50:37,469 [DEBUG] Running command 05-whenever
2013-04-06 14:50:37,470 [DEBUG] Generating defaults for command 05-whenever
<<<

2013-04-06 14:50:37,639 [DEBUG] Running test for command 05-whenever
2013-04-06 14:50:37,654 [DEBUG] Test command output: 
2013-04-06 14:50:37,654 [DEBUG] Test for command 05-whenever passed
2013-04-06 14:50:37,671 [INFO] Command 05-whenever succeeded
2013-04-06 14:50:37,671 [DEBUG] Command 05-whenever output: # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: [app name]
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/app/ondeck && script/rails runner -e production '\''TickerSymbol.update_prices'\'' >> /path/to/my/cron_log.log 2>&1'


# End Whenever generated tasks for: [app name]
```

Am I missing something? Based on the current configuration, I expect to see my log messages from TickerSymbol.update_prices inside my /var/log/cron_log.log file. However, I dont see any indication that these settings are producing an error nor do I see any indication that the cron job is running.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the output in the last log:

```
... cd /var/app/ondeck ...
```

This directory exists only during the deployment. If your crontab is setup to CD to it like it says, it won't work.